# The static folder does not contain the editted JS file?

Tags: magento2, cookie, gdpr, magentomodule

I am trying to edit one of the callbacks of the `gdpr-cookie` module in the directoy `vendor/amasty/gdpr-cookie/view/frontend/web/js/cookies.js`:

```
      allowCookies: function() {
            actionAllow().done(function() {

                //my code here

                $(this.barSelector).remove();
                cookieModel.triggerAllow();
            }.bind(this));
        },
```

But when I compile and build it:

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

The un-edited file show up in the static folder (`pub/static/frontend/.../Amasty_GdprCookie/js/cookies.js`) .
So the lines that I added are not there.
I also clear the cache each time.

What am I doing wrong? Is the module being loaded from another directory? Where should I edit it?

Comment: It could be a write permission issue. You can check it easily - just remove all visible content from the `pub/static/` (or just one file) and regenerate static content.

Comment: thanks. I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run these command and then check.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/
```

Comment: thanks. it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try 777 permission using the chmod command.